# Unable to click link in li tag in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, html-lists

I need to click a link which is inside

and  tag

I tried this but not able to click.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[(@class,'menuRoot')]")).click();
```

Note : this is inside the frame

below is the html code

```
<div class="menuRoot">
  <ul>
    <li onclick="selectRootItem(this)" documentid="1678" shrinkmenu="1"><a class="menu1" href="
                http://www.intellipen.LegalAndGeneral.pc/Resources/System/pages/read.aspx?DocID=1678" onclick="showLoading()" target="fraMain"><img src="
                  /Resources/System/images/icons/binoculars.png">Search</a></li>
    <li onclick="selectRootItem(this)" documentid="1585"><a class="menu1" href="
                http://www.intellipen.LegalAndGeneral.pc/Resources/System/pages/read.aspx?DocID=1585" onclick="showLoading()" target="fraMain"><img src="
                  /Resources/System/images/icons/member-data.png">Member</a></li>
    <li onclick="selectRootItem(this)" documentid="1581"><a class="menu1" href="
                http://www.intellipen.LegalAndGeneral.pc/Resources/System/pages/read.aspx?DocID=1581" onclick="showLoading()" target="fraMain"><img src="
                  /Resources/System/images/icons/member-wizard.png">Wizards</a></li>
    <li onclick="selectRootItem(this)" documentid="1605"><a class="menu1" href="
                http://www.intellipen.LegalAndGeneral.pc/Resources/System/pages/read.aspx?DocID=1605" onclick="showLoading()" target="fraMain"><img src="
                  /Resources/System/images/icons/browser.png">Establishment</a></li>
    <li onclick="selectRootItem(this)" documentid="1653"><a class="menu1" href="
                http://www.intellipen.LegalAndGeneral.pc/Resources/System/pages/read.aspx?DocID=1653" onclick="showLoading()" target="fraMain"><img src="
                  /Resources/System/images/icons/startup.png">Workflow</a></li>
```

Comment: There are so many links which you would like to click? If it is there inside frame then you need to switch to frame first.

Comment: //div[@class='menuRoot'] or //div[contains(@class,'menuRoot')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on the menu based on the text present in the menu. Here is some samples,

**Search Menu item**--

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Search')]//parent::li")).click();
```

**Member menu item --**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Member')]//parent::li")).click();
```

Comment: If i try above xpath getting this error Given xpath expression "//li/a[contains(text(),'Workflow']" is invalid:

Comment: Still getting the same error.      " org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <a class="menu1" href="

Comment: It is a different error. The element identification is working, but interactable. Can you post the full stack trace.?

Comment: 'li' element has onclick method call. you can try click on the li element rather than its anchor element. see updated answer.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <a class="menu1" href="
                http://www.intellipen.LegalAndGeneral.pc/Resources/System/pages/read.aspx?DocID=1653"> could not be scrolled into view
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'CWQFQV2', ip: '192.168.0.87', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '13'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Search')]//parent::li")).click(); this xpath worked.Thanks a lot

Comment: If it solves the problem, request you to upvote the answer. thanks!

Comment: I have updated.this xpath works driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Search')]//parent::li")).click();